# How can I covert multiple svg's into a png as it is they are on html?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I want exact png of my svg displayed on page as an output, Is it       possible?

I have my html code here :

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Vikas</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
      <svg width="50" height="50">
         <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="purple" />
      </svg>
      <svg width="50" height="50">
         <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="purple" />
      </svg>
      <svg width="100" height="100">
         <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="purple" />
      </svg>
      <svg width="400" height="110">
         <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);strokewidth:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
      </svg>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Html5 canvas has drawing commands that are almost identical to SVG's drawing commands. F.ex:  `context.fillStyle='purple';` will set your fill to be  purple and `context.arc(25,25,25,0,Math.PI*2); context.fill();` will draw your circle. Learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some libraries to convert some part of the DOM to images. 
This is one of them: https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

Maybe you can find it useful

Try something like this example:

```js
window.onload= function() {
  
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('myDrawing'))
  .then(function (dataUrl) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
  });
  
};

//Libraries here:


/*! dom-to-image 24-04-2016 */
!function(a){"use strict";function b(a,b){function c(a){return b.bgcolor&&(a.style.backgroundColor=b.bgcolor),b.width&&(a.style.width=b.width+"px"),b.height&&(a.style.height=b.height+"px"),b.style&&Object.keys(b.style).forEach(function(c){a.style[c]=b.style[c]}),a}return b=b||{},Promise.resolve(a).then(function(a){return g(a,b.filter,!0)}).then(h).then(i).then(c).then(function(c){return j(c,b.width||a.scrollWidth,b.height||a.scrollHeight)})}function c(a,b){return f(a,b||{}).then(function(b){return b.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,a.scrollWidth,a.scrollHeight).data})}function d(a,b){return f(a,b||{}).then(function(a){return a.toDataURL()})}function e(a,b){return f(a,b||{}).then(o.canvasToBlob)}function f(a,c){function d(a){var b=document.createElement("canvas");return b.width=c.width||a.scrollWidth,b.height=c.height||a.scrollHeight,b}return b(a,c).then(o.makeImage).then(o.delay(100)).then(function(b){var c=d(a);return c.getContext("2d").drawImage(b,0,0),c})}function g(a,b,c){function d(a){return a instanceof HTMLCanvasElement?o.makeImage(a.toDataURL()):a.cloneNode(!1)}function e(a,b,c){function d(a,b,c){var d=Promise.resolve();return b.forEach(function(b){d=d.then(function(){return g(b,c)}).then(function(b){b&&a.appendChild(b)})}),d}var e=a.childNodes;return 0===e.length?Promise.resolve(b):d(b,o.asArray(e),c).then(function(){return b})}function f(a,b){function c(){function c(a,b){function c(a,b){o.asArray(a).forEach(function(c){b.setProperty(c,a.getPropertyValue(c),a.getPropertyPriority(c))})}a.cssText?b.cssText=a.cssText:c(a,b)}c(window.getComputedStyle(a),b.style)}function d(){function c(c){function d(a,b,c){function d(a){var b=a.getPropertyValue("content");return a.cssText+" content: "+b+";"}function e(a){function b(b){return b+": "+a.getPropertyValue(b)+(a.getPropertyPriority(b)?" !important":"")}return o.asArray(a).map(b).join("; ")+";"}var f="."+a+":"+b,g=c.cssText?d(c):e(c);return document.createTextNode(f+"{"+g+"}")}var e=window.getComputedStyle(a,c),f=e.getPropertyValue("content");if(""!==f&&"none"!==f){var g=o.uid();b.className=b.className+" "+g;var h=document.createElement("style");h.appendChild(d(g,c,e)),b.appendChild(h)}}[":before",":after"].forEach(function(a){c(a)})}function e(){a instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement&&(b.innerHTML=a.value),a instanceof HTMLInputElement&&b.setAttribute("value",a.value)}function f(){b instanceof SVGElement&&(b.setAttribute("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"),b instanceof SVGRectElement&&["width","height"].forEach(function(a){var c=b.getAttribute(a);c&&b.style.setProperty(a,c)}))}return b instanceof Element?Promise.resolve().then(c).then(d).then(e).then(f).then(function(){return b}):b}return c||!b||b(a)?Promise.resolve(a).then(d).then(function(c){return e(a,c,b)}).then(function(b){return f(a,b)}):Promise.resolve()}function h(a){return q.resolveAll().then(function(b){var c=document.createElement("style");return a.appendChild(c),c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(b)),a})}function i(a){return r.inlineAll(a).then(function(){return a})}function j(a,b,c){return Promise.resolve(a).then(function(a){return a.setAttribute("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"),(new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(a)}).then(o.escapeXhtml).then(function(a){return'<foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">'+a+"</foreignObject>"}).then(function(a){return'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="'+b+'" height="'+c+'">'+a+"</svg>"}).then(function(a){return"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,"+a})}function k(){function a(){var a="application/font-woff",b="image/jpeg";return{woff:a,woff2:a,ttf:"application/font-truetype",eot:"application/vnd.ms-fontobject",png:"image/png",jpg:b,jpeg:b,gif:"image/gif",tiff:"image/tiff",svg:"image/svg+xml"}}function b(a){var b=/\.([^\.\/]*?)$/g.exec(a);return b?b[1]:""}function c(c){var d=b(c).toLowerCase();return a()[d]||""}function d(a){return-1!==a.search(/^(data:)/)}function e(a){return new Promise(function(b){for(var c=window.atob(a.toDataURL().split(",")[1]),d=c.length,e=new Uint8Array(d),f=0;d>f;f++)e[f]=c.charCodeAt(f);b(new Blob([e],{type:"image/png"}))})}function f(a){return a.toBlob?new Promise(function(b){a.toBlob(b)}):e(a)}function g(a,b){var c=document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(),d=c.createElement("base");c.head.appendChild(d);var e=c.createElement("a");return c.body.appendChild(e),d.href=b,e.href=a,e.href}function h(){var a=0;return function(){function b(){return("0000"+(Math.random()*Math.pow(36,4)<<0).toString(36)).slice(-4)}return"u"+b()+a++}}function i(a){return new Promise(function(b,c){var d=new Image;d.onload=function(){b(d)},d.onerror=c,d.src=a})}function j(a){var b=3e4;return new Promise(function(c){function d(){if(4===g.readyState){if(200!==g.status)return void f("cannot fetch resource: "+a+", status: "+g.status);var b=new FileReader;b.onloadend=function(){var a=b.result.split(/,/)[1];c(a)},b.readAsDataURL(g.response)}}function e(){f("timeout of "+b+"ms occured while fetching resource: "+a)}function f(a){console.error(a),c("")}var g=new XMLHttpRequest;g.onreadystatechange=d,g.ontimeout=e,g.responseType="blob",g.timeout=b,g.open("GET",a,!0),g.send()})}function k(a,b){return"data:"+b+";base64,"+a}function l(a){return a.replace(/([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g,"\\$1")}function m(a){return function(b){return new Promise(function(c){setTimeout(function(){c(b)},a)})}}function n(a){for(var b=[],c=a.length,d=0;c>d;d++)b.push(a[d]);return b}function o(a){return a.replace(/#/g,"%23").replace(/\n/g,"%0A")}return{escape:l,parseExtension:b,mimeType:c,dataAsUrl:k,isDataUrl:d,canvasToBlob:f,resolveUrl:g,getAndEncode:j,uid:h(),delay:m,asArray:n,escapeXhtml:o,makeImage:i}}function l(){function a(a){return-1!==a.search(e)}function b(a){for(var b,c=[];null!==(b=e.exec(a));)c.push(b[1]);return c.filter(function(a){return!o.isDataUrl(a)})}function c(a,b,c,d){function e(a){return new RegExp("(url\\(['\"]?)("+o.escape(a)+")(['\"]?\\))","g")}return Promise.resolve(b).then(function(a){return c?o.resolveUrl(a,c):a}).then(d||o.getAndEncode).then(function(a){return o.dataAsUrl(a,o.mimeType(b))}).then(function(c){return a.replace(e(b),"$1"+c+"$3")})}function d(d,e,f){function g(){return!a(d)}return g()?Promise.resolve(d):Promise.resolve(d).then(b).then(function(a){var b=Promise.resolve(d);return a.forEach(function(a){b=b.then(function(b){return c(b,a,e,f)})}),b})}var e=/url\(['"]?([^'"]+?)['"]?\)/g;return{inlineAll:d,shouldProcess:a,impl:{readUrls:b,inline:c}}}function m(){function a(){return b(document).then(function(a){return Promise.all(a.map(function(a){return a.resolve()}))}).then(function(a){return a.join("\n")})}function b(){function a(a){return a.filter(function(a){return a.type===CSSRule.FONT_FACE_RULE}).filter(function(a){return p.shouldProcess(a.style.getPropertyValue("src"))})}function b(a){var b=[];return a.forEach(function(a){try{o.asArray(a.cssRules||[]).forEach(b.push.bind(b))}catch(c){console.log("Error while reading CSS rules from "+a.href,c.toString())}}),b}function c(a){return{resolve:function(){var b=(a.parentStyleSheet||{}).href;return p.inlineAll(a.cssText,b)},src:function(){return a.style.getPropertyValue("src")}}}return Promise.resolve(o.asArray(document.styleSheets)).then(b).then(a).then(function(a){return a.map(c)})}return{resolveAll:a,impl:{readAll:b}}}function n(){function a(a){function b(b){return o.isDataUrl(a.src)?Promise.resolve():Promise.resolve(a.src).then(b||o.getAndEncode).then(function(b){return o.dataAsUrl(b,o.mimeType(a.src))}).then(function(b){return new Promise(function(c,d){a.onload=c,a.onerror=d,a.src=b})})}return{inline:b}}function b(c){function d(a){var b=a.style.getPropertyValue("background");return b?p.inlineAll(b).then(function(b){a.style.setProperty("background",b,a.style.getPropertyPriority("background"))}).then(function(){return a}):Promise.resolve(a)}return c instanceof Element?d(c).then(function(){return c instanceof HTMLImageElement?a(c).inline():Promise.all(o.asArray(c.childNodes).map(function(a){return b(a)}))}):Promise.resolve(c)}return{inlineAll:b,impl:{newImage:a}}}var o=k(),p=l(),q=m(),r=n(),s={toSvg:b,toPng:d,toBlob:e,toPixelData:c,impl:{fontFaces:q,images:r,util:o,inliner:p}};"undefined"!=typeof module?module.exports=s:a.domtoimage=s}(this);

/*! @source http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js */
var saveAs=saveAs||function(e){"use strict";if("undefined"==typeof navigator||!/MSIE [1-9]\./.test(navigator.userAgent)){var t=e.document,n=function(){return e.URL||e.webkitURL||e},o=t.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","a"),r="download"in o,i=function(e){var t=new MouseEvent("click");e.dispatchEvent(t)},a=/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent),c=e.webkitRequestFileSystem,f=e.requestFileSystem||c||e.mozRequestFileSystem,u=function(t){(e.setImmediate||e.setTimeout)(function(){throw t},0)},d="application/octet-stream",s=0,l=4e4,v=function(e){var t=function(){"string"==typeof e?n().revokeObjectURL(e):e.remove()};setTimeout(t,l)},p=function(e,t,n){t=[].concat(t);for(var o=t.length;o--;){var r=e["on"+t[o]];if("function"==typeof r)try{r.call(e,n||e)}catch(i){u(i)}}},w=function(e){return/^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;.*charset\s*=\s*utf-8/i.test(e.type)?new Blob(["\ufeff",e],{type:e.type}):e},y=function(t,u,l){l||(t=w(t));var y,m,S,h=this,R=t.type,O=!1,g=function(){p(h,"writestart progress write writeend".split(" "))},b=function(){if(m&&a&&"undefined"!=typeof FileReader){var o=new FileReader;return o.onloadend=function(){var e=o.result;m.location.href="data:attachment/file"+e.slice(e.search(/[,;]/)),h.readyState=h.DONE,g()},o.readAsDataURL(t),void(h.readyState=h.INIT)}if((O||!y)&&(y=n().createObjectURL(t)),m)m.location.href=y;else{var r=e.open(y,"_blank");void 0===r&&a&&(e.location.href=y)}h.readyState=h.DONE,g(),v(y)},E=function(e){return function(){return h.readyState!==h.DONE?e.apply(this,arguments):void 0}},N={create:!0,exclusive:!1};return h.readyState=h.INIT,u||(u="download"),r?(y=n().createObjectURL(t),void setTimeout(function(){o.href=y,o.download=u,i(o),g(),v(y),h.readyState=h.DONE})):(e.chrome&&R&&R!==d&&(S=t.slice||t.webkitSlice,t=S.call(t,0,t.size,d),O=!0),c&&"download"!==u&&(u+=".download"),(R===d||c)&&(m=e),f?(s+=t.size,void f(e.TEMPORARY,s,E(function(e){e.root.getDirectory("saved",N,E(function(e){var n=function(){e.getFile(u,N,E(function(e){e.createWriter(E(function(n){n.onwriteend=function(t){m.location.href=e.toURL(),h.readyState=h.DONE,p(h,"writeend",t),v(e)},n.onerror=function(){var e=n.error;e.code!==e.ABORT_ERR&&b()},"writestart progress write abort".split(" ").forEach(function(e){n["on"+e]=h["on"+e]}),n.write(t),h.abort=function(){n.abort(),h.readyState=h.DONE},h.readyState=h.WRITING}),b)}),b)};e.getFile(u,{create:!1},E(function(e){e.remove(),n()}),E(function(e){e.code===e.NOT_FOUND_ERR?n():b()}))}),b)}),b)):void b())},m=y.prototype,S=function(e,t,n){return new y(e,t,n)};return"undefined"!=typeof navigator&&navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob?function(e,t,n){return n||(e=w(e)),navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(e,t||"download")}:(m.abort=function(){var e=this;e.readyState=e.DONE,p(e,"abort")},m.readyState=m.INIT=0,m.WRITING=1,m.DONE=2,m.error=m.onwritestart=m.onprogress=m.onwrite=m.onabort=m.onerror=m.onwriteend=null,S)}}("undefined"!=typeof self&&self||"undefined"!=typeof window&&window||this.content);"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports.saveAs=saveAs:"undefined"!=typeof define&&null!==define&&null!==define.amd&&define([],function(){return saveAs});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/master/dist/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>
  <html>
 <head>
 <title>Vikas</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   
   <div id="myDrawing">
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
 <svg width="50" height="50">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="purple" />
</svg>

 <svg width="50" height="50">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="purple" />
 </svg>

  <svg width="100" height="100">
     <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="purple" />
  </svg>

  <svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);strokewidth:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">

    </svg>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

(Please note that I pasted both libraries dom-to-image and FileSaver, in my javascript. You should include sepparated js files instead)

Also, I included a wrapping  element with id="myDrawing"

Comment: thanks for your comment can you make a fiddle of using one of them to convert them in a png

Comment: Done, edited my answer including to include the fiddle

Comment: Thanks for your effort buddy